# How do I allow traffic only to may main page, all subdomains and path will be blocked in cloudflare

Tags: cloudflare

I want to allow traffic only to my main site's landing page.
Example: domain-name.com
This can be accessed by all countries without limitation.

My subdomains and all paths however should be limited only to a specific country.
example:

domain-name.com/login

domain-name.com/dashboard

sub.domain-name.com/login

sub.domain-name.com/dashboard

All these shall be restricted.

Here's what I did so far:
I went to cloudflare, under security-> WAF, i create 2 rules:

1. Field: Hostname Operator: equals, Value: yourdomain.com, Choose Action: Skip.
2. Field: Country Operator: equals, Value: country, Choose Action: Block.

I opened a VPN to that country other than the value, it is restricted. I cannot open it.
What should I do?